# Sending "data" in res.send(), gives error on front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to send the data in res.send(data). When i

```
console.log("This dox data",text);
```

in terminal, it works fine. It logs all text content in terminal. But accessing at frontend it gives me error

```
router.get("/api/emailtemplates/data/:subject", (req, res) => {
  Email_templates.find({subject: req.params.subject}, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      const val = data[0]['template_file_link'];
      console.log(val);
     const data= textract.fromFileWithPath(val, function( error, text ) {
        console.log("This dox data",text);
    });
    
    res.send(data);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: What error and how do you call it

Comment: @achyuta - What error you are getting ?

Comment: App.js 
const onsubjectChange = (value,e)=>{setLink(e.label); setChooseSubject(value);console.log("this is subject",value)}
Service.js

export const getEmailTemplateSub = (state="")=>{
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/api/emailtemplates/data`).then(res => state(res.data) ).catch(err=>console.log(err))
};

Comment: <Select
                                    getPopupContainer={(trigger) =>trigger.parentElement}
                                    showSearch
                                    onFocus={getSubjectList}
                                    onChange={onsubjectChange}
                                    placeholder="Select Subject.."
                               >{showSubject}
                                </Select>
while i select subject in frontend i get an error 
events.js:292  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' eventTypeError: Cannot read property 'template_file_link' of undefined

Comment: Update the question instead of posting code in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to return wrong thing you need to send response in callback of the textract function

```
router.get('/api/emailtemplates/data/:subject', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const templates = await Email_templates.find({ subject: req.params.subject });
    const val = templates[0].template_file_link;
    console.log(val);
    textract.fromFileWithPath(val, (error, text) => {
      console.log('This dox data', text);
      return res.json({ text });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: true });
  }
});
```

Comment: What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: I changed the place where it was sent to the client and reformatted to async/await syntax

Comment: Thanks @LucjanGrzesik ,it works.

Comment: why did you unaccepted the answer @AchyutaNantaPanda?

Comment: sorry Lucjan Grzesik, i am new to stack overflow , i dont know how to use it.

Comment: i accepted your answer and it works fine. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

That code will give you the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization`. You're trying to use the `data` constant you've declared within the `if (!err)` block before that constant has been initialized, because you've used `data` both as the name of the parameter you're going to receive the data from `Email_templates.find` in and also as the constant you store the result of `textract.fromFileWithPath` in. Here's a simpler example of the problem:

```js
function example(err, data) {
    //                ^^^^−−−−−−− parameter called `data`
    if (!err) {
        const val = data[0]['template_file_link'];
        //          ^^^^−−−−−−−−− ReferenceError here
        //              because this is trying to use
        //              the constant below before it's
        //              initialized (it's in the "Temporal
        //              Dead Zone")
        
        const data = "whatever";
    }
}
example(null, [{template_file_link: ""}]);
```

Use different names for them. For instance:

```
router.get("/api/emailtemplates/data/:subject", (req, res) => {
    Email_templates.find({subject: req.params.subject}, (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
            const val = data[0]['template_file_link'];
            console.log(val);
            const fileData = textract.fromFileWithPath(val, function( error, text ) {
            //    ^^^^^^^^
                console.log("This dox data",text);
            });

            res.send(fileData);
            //       ^^^^^^^^
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```